# Repeated field validation

Tags: symfony

I have two questions according to this part of code:

```
$builder->add('password', 'repeated', [
                    'label' => 'Repeat password',
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'first_name' => 'password',
                    'second_name' => 'password2',
                    'error_bubbling' => true,
                    'invalid_message' => 'Password does not match']);
```

1. Why do I keep getting "This value should not be blank" validation error?
2. I display these validation errors using the following syntax:

   {{ form_errors(form) }}

Is it possible to separate single field errors?

Comment: What does `error_bubbling` ?? Anyway, I don't know why your code isn't working, but I paste here a piece of working code of mine: `->add('password', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'invalid_message' => 'Must match!'))` This code is working, if you copy-paste it and still not getting your custom invalid message... the problem could be in another place.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt the "This value should not be blank" validation error is casued by your repeated field.

You seem to have a `NotBlank` validation constraint set up as annotation/yml/xml for some field which does not validate.

just dump `$form->getErrorsAsString` to get a field-name as key => error-messages array and inspect which field causes the `NotBlank` constraint to fail ...

... or just have a look at your validation constraints and find the properties with `NotBlank` constraints.